# Carbon Wheel Heat Bending

Tags: carbon

After riding about 800m downhill, I got this:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

BTW, this is TriAce Wheelset for Dahon Mu Ex 2014. Do you think this is safe to ride? Can I repair this?

Comment: In answer to your questions: IMHO no and no.

Comment: Was that 800m vertical or horizontal?

Comment: horizontal (-100m vertical)!

Comment: Wow. No and no.

Comment: So apparently carbon rims should only be used with disk brakes.

Comment: Well, you need to be [careful](http://www.bikeradar.com/us/gear/article/are-carbon-fiber-clinchers-safe-34521/) with rim brakes and carbon.

Comment: By reparing that one it will become a death trap!

Comment: Uhm, carbon shatters it doesn't bend what are these made off? And does m stand for miles?

Comment: @DanielRHicks: not necessary, it seems these were made by a BSO brand.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To answer your questions

- No, they are not safe to ride due to risk of the tube blowing out or the tire rolling off the rim.
- No, I do not think they are repairable (at home). If they were repaired I would not trust them again.

I believe that this item is not fit for the purpose of a bicycle wheel.

It should be returned to the place of purchase on those grounds and a replacement or refund sought.

Comment: Assuming the OP was riding on surfaces appropriate for the wheel, I completely agree it should be returned. And I'd want a refund, not a replacement.

Comment: It's TriAce wheelsset for my Dahon. I used Shimano carbon break pad installed by the shop. They said it's my fault, since I use the break too much/strong. No refund. No Warrantee.

Comment: It seems triace is a BSO brand, and dahon is a folding bike maker, but that doesn't look like a folding bike's wheel. Where did you obtain this wheel?

Comment: By any chance did you record this ride with a GPS app of some sort? I find it really hard to believe that you overheated the rims enough to do that with just 100m of descent unless that 100m was all at once and at a ridiculously steep grade.

Comment: @SungKim You say *No Warrantee*. But most countries have laws requiring merchandise to be *fit for purpose*, and such laws usually include *reasonable use* conditions. We are not lawyers, and this site is not for legal advice, but I think it would be worth checking out. For example, in Australia the state governments each have a Department of Consumer Affairs (or similar). Complaints to them often have severe consequences for the supplier of dodgy goods, at no cost to the consumer. Even threatening to lodge a complaint often brings an instant change of supplier attitude. Good luck.

Comment: @Garey See here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/s6d68x7qm2ns4wl/Screenshot%202015-03-05%2008.45.16.png?dl=0 This happened in the first half of the downhill.

Comment: @whatsisname in the Hong Kong local bike shop.

Comment: @SungKim See [Hong Kong Consumer Council](http://www.consumer.org.hk/website/ws_en/complaints_and_advices/how_to_complain/howtocomplain.html)

Comment: I lived in Hong Kong for a few years and the consumer rights are nowhere near the standard found in the UK. I'd imagine a small wheel will generate more heat at the rim when braking. Miniature and folding bikes are very popular in Hong Kong where space for storing of bicycles is at a premium in small Hong Kong flats. There are all sorts of ways to "pimp" up a miniature bike - it would almost make no sense to put carbon wheels on a folding bike and then take it down a mountain descent. But there you go - I think you found the extremes of their usage - hope you get recompense for the wheels.

Comment: @OraNob Smaller wheels do not generate more heat - the kinetic energy to be dissipated is the same regardless of wheel size. Due to the terrain it's almost impossible to go anywhere without a descent.

Comment: Smaller wheels have less swept area to dissipate heat. But, that notwithstanding, tell them you want a refund then go to a reputable shop and get an alloy wheel.

Comment: Apologies if I was wrong thinking - small wheels more heat build-up. It was basically thinking along the lines of for a given speed the smaller wheel must be rotating faster than a larger wheel - that's all.

Comment: @OraNob No need to apologize. As Chris says, smaller wheels have less area to dissipate the same heat energy.