# a carbon rim cost only $169 is real carbon?

Tags: rims, price

Wanna upgrade my bike to carbon,and find this rim [http://www.carbonbikeoem.com/bike-rims/mtb](http://www.carbonbikeoem.com/2015-new-arrival/bike-rims/mtb/xc-series/26er/2014-carbonbikeoem-26er-xc-mtb-carbon-rims-30mm-width-cross-country-mountain-bicycle) cost only $169,so is this a real carbon?and what is the general price of carbon rims?

Comment: Being too careful in this matter won't hurt. If you doubt product quality, go look for reviews, and if there are none then find something more popular and tested by real people. There are reputable chinese carbon rim sellers, check out [mtbr](http://forums.mtbr.com/forum.php) and [weighweenies](http://weightweenies.starbike.com/forum/) for exact names. These helped a lot when I was in market for carbon rims.

Comment: First ask yourself WHY do you want to upgrade to carbon.

Comment: It is real carbon.  Will it hold up is another question.

Answer (score 10):

I would be very careful with a deal that sounds too good to be true.  Take a look at what happend to this carbon wheel in another question: [Carbon Wheel Heat Bending](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/29272/carbon-wheel-heat-bending)

I wouldn't buy from a company I've never heard of before and will never hear from again (like when the wheel deforms from the heat of braking and I'm trying to get a refund). Even the tagline on that website ("Welcome to carbonbikeoem.com , enjoy the great savings now!") is a red flag to me.  It suggests that the only point of their products is that they're cheap. The generally poor grammar of that website also suggests that it's not a serious company, but just someone who can cheaply produce things from something resembling carbon fiber.

It would be much better to get a decent set of aluminum wheels, then you don't have to worry about how long they last before they snap.  For $85, you can get a Mavic XC 717 Disc rim that weighs 395 grams.  Mavic is a well-known manufacturer and you are guaranteed that this is a good product.  It weighs 35 grams more than those carbon rims.  Who cares about 35 grams ?

Comment: I completely agree.

Comment: If something happens the manufacturer and the seller sit in China. You will have to claim at a Chinese court. Good luck!